# Why is the same jsonpath query returning a different output?

Tags: kubernetes, jq, jsonpath

I am trying to extract podname using the below jq query.

```sh
❯ kubectl get pods -l app=mssql-primary --output jsonpath='{.items[0].metadata.name}'
mssqlag-primary-deployment-77b8974bb9-dbltl%                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
❯ kubectl get pods -l app=mssql-primary -o json | jq -r '.items[0].metadata.name'
mssqlag-primary-deployment-77b8974bb9-dbltl
```

While they both provide the same out put the first one has a % character at the end of the pod name. Any reason why ? Is there something wrong with the jsonpath representation in the first command ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I reproduced your case with the same deployment name and label. And I get the same output from both of your commands:

```sh
mssqlag-primary-deployment-77b8974bb9-dbltl
```

But `kubectl ... --output jsonpath` does not print a new line in terminal while `kubectl -o json | jq -r` prints new line.

So, if you assign the output of your commands to a variable, there will be the same string.

```sh
OUTPUT1=$(kubectl get pods -l app=mssql-primary --output jsonpath='{.items[0].metadata.name}')
OUTPUT2=$(kubectl get pods -l app=mssql-primary -o json | jq -r '.items[0].metadata.name')
```

The $OUTPUT1 is equal to $OUTPUT2.

And you got % just because of the specifics of your shell/terminal.

Comment: Yes, assigning to a variable works and removes the % . I am using zsh and it adds the % at the end.

```shell
 ip1=$(kubectl get service mssql-primary --output jsonpath='{.status.loadBalancer.ingress[0].ip}')
❯ echo $ip1
xx.xx.xxx.xxx
```
PS : i have masked the IP address

Answer (score 3):

I'm guessing `zsh` is your shell. The `%` is an indicator output by your shell to say that the last line output by `kubectl` had no newline character at the end. So it's not *extra* output, it's actually an indicator that the raw `kubectl` command outputs *less* than `jq`.

You could explicitly add a newline to the jsonpath output if you want it:

```
kubectl get pods -l app=mssql-primary --output jsonpath='{.items[0].metadata.name}{"\n"}'
```

Or in the other direction you could tell `jq` not to add newlines at all by specifying `-j` instead of `-r`:

```
kubectl get pods -l app=mssql-primary -o json | jq -j '.items[0].metadata.name'
```

Comment: Yes, it is due to zsh. Thanks for pointing it out. jq -j does not seem to work however

```shell
❯ kubectl get pods -l app=mssql-primary -o json | jq -j '.items[0].metadata.name'
mssqlag-primary-deployment-77b8974bb9-dbltl%
```